# Split string in two groups with regex and show only the last group

Tags: regex

I have some similar properties. First I need to select the property and second I want to have the value as result of a regular expression.

Data:

```
BlockSize:4096
TotalBlocks:68822
HighWater:68764
FreeBlocks:2553
RecordBlocks:25378
BIBlocksize:8192
BIClustersize:512
```

The regular expression to split them in two groups is: `(FreeBlocks):(.*$)`. Now I want only the value (2e group) as the result. I want to use these expressions in a Zabbix key.

Comment: Could you please write your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

Accoring to the documentation [zabbix](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/regular_expressions) uses PCRE. In that case you might use `\K` to reset the starting point of the reported match and match one or more time a digit `\d+` or use `.*` to match any character zero or more times.

This will give you a match instead of a capturing group. If you do want the group you could use parenthesis `(\d+)`

[`FreeBlocks:\K\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/e1WNtx/1)

To match all before the colon you could use a negated character class:

[`^[^:]+:\K\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/e1WNtx/2)